# How to close out of the file opener without an error?

Tags: python, pyqt5

When I click the open button, the GUI gives me the option to select a file. If I close out of file selector, an error appears. How to I keep this from happening?

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.Open = QPushButton('Open')
        self.Open.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.show()
        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.Open)

    def open(self):
        name = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File')
        file = open(name[0], 'r')
        lines = file.readlines()
        print(lines)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if valid `name`

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QPushButton

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.Open = QPushButton('Open')
        self.Open.clicked.connect(self.open)
        self.show()
        layout = QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.Open)

    def open(self):
        name, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, 'Select File')
        if name:                                 # <---
            with open(name) as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                print(*lines, sep='\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```